# Device Orientation with JavaScript - Working on iPhone but not iPad

Tags: javascript, webview, orientation, device

I am relatively new to developing on the iOS. I am trying to detect orientation changes using javascript in a html file, and then load that local HTML file with a WebView object. The following code is the JS from my HTML file. It works perfectly on an iPhone, but NOT on an iPad. Both devices have iOS version 4.2 or higher, and should support device orientation. LR, FB, and dir are just div elements in my body that I am using to track the orientation changes. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(eventData) {
    var LR = eventData.gamma;
    var FB = eventData.beta;``
    var DIR = eventData.alpha;
    deviceOrientationHandler(LR, FB, DIR);                
});

function deviceOrientationHandler(LR, FB, DIR) {
    document.getElementById("LR").innerHTML = "Left/Right : " + LR;
    document.getElementById("FB").innerHTML = "Front/Back : " + FB;
    document.getElementById("dir").innerHTML = "Direction : " + DIR;
}
```